# testing expressjs routes by using nextjs

Tags: node.js, express, testing, next.js

I'm trying to use nextjs within my app, was able to make it working with express as expected, but stuck with tests. How to test those app, which wrapped  with nextjs?

server.js

```
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nextApp = next({ dev })
    const app = express();
    nextApp.prepare()
      .then(() => {
        const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes")(nextApp);
        app.use("/", userRoutes);


        app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
          const actualPage = '/index'
          const query = { id: 'reqaramshhjjkkllvvoooo', test: 'testPropertyNN' } 
          nextApp.render(req, res,  '/index', query);
        })


        server =  app.listen(PORT)

    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      console.error(ex.stack)
      process.exit(1)
    })

    module.exports = app;
```

and test it with this below, but receiving 404, how jest should be configured along with next what test would work? I'm just switching from  create-react-app to nextjs but failing at test(without next managed it works), anyone has an example or any clue to get those work?

```
  it('should get it workin', done => {
    agent
      .get(`/test`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        should.not.exist(err);
        res.status.should.equal(200);
        done();
      })
  })
```

Comment: the problem were just in development with nextjs, where prepare() holds the app to start and why 404. solved in dev with checking environment during the test like so process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' vs production/development/test

Comment: I have the same issue with prepare(). Could you provide more details about how did you use NODE_ENV to solve your problem?

Comment: just test next app with production next({ dev: false or? true }), couse, probably, additional tasks is done in next dev mode.

Comment: any fix for this?